# VBScript redirects user to label

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have recently started coding in VBScript and I have a work where I have a batch file called `Game.bat` located in the folder `C:\Velocity DK\My Game`.

In my game, the user gets to login to the app. The basic script works just fine, but here is the problem. I have a .vbs file that opens when the user inputs wrong information to the batch file. Though, I can't find a way to make the VBS file redirect to the label I want the user to be going on depending on which button the user pressed.

The batch file looks a bit similar to this:

```
@echo off
:RETRY
:MAIN
cls
echo Please input valid information.
echo.
set /p username=Username: 
set /p password=Password: 
if exist %USERPROFILE%\Game\"%username%"\username.sav if exist %USERPROFILE%\Game\"%username%"\username.sav goto game
if not exist %USERPROFILE%\Game\"%username%"\username.sav if not exist %USERPROFILE%\Game\"%username%"\username.sav (
    cls
    start /wait "" C:\"Velocity DK"\"My Game"\Invalid.vbs
)
goto MAIN

:: My Game's code is located here

:FORCE_QUIT
cls
exit /force
goto FORCE_QUIT
```

My VBS file looks like this:

```
returnvalue = MsgBox "Do. you want to retry?",4,"My Game"
if returnvalue = 7 then
    ' Some code to redirect to batch file label :FORCE_EXIT
    WScript.Quit
else
    ' Some code to redirect to the batch file label :RETRY
end if
```

In brief, I would like to know how I could make it so that when the user presses the yes button, he gets taken back to the `:RETRY` label of the batch file other wise, he will be taken to the `:FORCE_QUIT` label. How can I do so?

Comment: This sounds more like a vbs problem as you would probably want to write the code to redirect the user properly in the vbs script.

Comment: What does help say about `wscript.quit`?

Comment: It's not possible for the vb app to specify a target label in the batch file.  What you can do, is have the vb script return a non-zero value that you then pick up as %ERRORLEVEL% in the batch script and you can use that to decide which label to call or goto.

Comment: You also don't need the vbs file. Just use the choice command in your batch script.  Try `choice /?` and read the results.

Comment: Also, if x if x ..., is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use the **argument**/**parameter** to call your **file.bat** from your **file.vbs** to do this?...

Basically, with some cope editions the **VBS** and **BAT** file, to handle the argument/parameter and behave from these values..

> The **bat code** above, will write the **vbs** file for you and **execute** the vbs.
>
> **Call from vbs:** <kbd>**`file.bat :label`**</kbd>

```bat
@echo off 
for %%a in (%*) do if /i "%1" equ "%%a" goto %%a

>"%temp%\Q_SO55201139.vbs"^
    (
     echo/ Option Explicit
     echo/ Dim WshShell,StrArg0, StrArg1, StrArg2, Result
     echo/ Set WshShell = Wscript.CreateObject^("Wscript.Shell"^)
     echo/ StrArg0 = Chr^(34^) ^& "%~f0" ^& Chr^(34^)
     echo/ StrArg1 = Chr^(34^) ^& ":RETRY" ^& Chr^(34^)
     echo/ StrArg2 = Chr^(34^) ^& ":FORCE_QUIT" ^& Chr^(34^)
     echo/ Result = MsgBox^("Do you want to retry?",vbyesno,"My Game"^)
     echo/ if  Result = VbNo then
     echo/     WshShell.Run ^(StrArg0 ^& StrArg2^),1,True
     echo/ else
     echo/     WshShell.Run ^(StrArg0 ^& StrArg1^),1,True
     echo/ end if
    )
    
:RETRY

:MAIN

cls
echo Please input valid information.
echo.

set /p "username=Username: "
set /p "password=Password: "

if exist "%USERPROFILE%\Game\"%username%"\username.sav" if exist "%USERPROFILE%\Game\"%username%"\username.sav" goto :game
if not exist "%USERPROFILE%\Game\"%username%"\username.sav" if not exist "%USERPROFILE%\Game\"%username%"\username.sav" (

    cls & start "" /w "%Windir%\System32\wScript.exe" //nologo "C:\Velocity DK\My Game\Invalid.vbs"

    )

start "" /w "%Windir%\System32\wScript.exe" //nologo "%temp%\Q_SO55201139.vbs" && exit /b

goto MAIN

:: My Game's code is located here

:FORCE_QUIT
cls & exit /force

goto :FORCE_QUIT

del /q /f "%temp%\Q_SO55201139.vbs" 2>nul >nul
```

> <kbd>**`Vbs file code`**</kbd>

```vbs
Option Explicit
Dim WshShell,StrArg0, StrArg1, StrArg2, Result
Set WshShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
StrArg0 = Chr(34) & "game_cmd_vbs.cmd" & Chr(34)
StrArg1 = Chr(34) & ":RETRY" & Chr(34)
StrArg2 = Chr(34) & ":FORCE_QUIT" & Chr(34)
Result = MsgBox("Do you want to retry?",vbyesno,"My Game")
if  Result = VbNo then
    WshShell.Run (StrArg0 & StrArg2),1,True
else
    WshShell.Run (StrArg0 & StrArg1),1,True
end if
```

> **Obs.:** You need add fullpath in line 5th: <kbd>**`c:\full\path\to\file\game_bat_vbs.cmd`**</kbd>

Sorry my *limited* **English!**

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly fine. It also respects all of my work assignment criteria from my school.

Answer (score 0):

### Choice

I would handle this with the `CHOICE` command:

```
CHOICE /M "Do. you want to retry?"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 GOTO RETRY
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 2 GOTO FORCE_QUIT
```

This way there is no need for VBS at all.

### Errorlevel

However, if your VBS will have code that is difficult or impossible to do in a batch file, you could have your `.vbs` file return an error code. The `START /WAIT` command will pass that code on to the `%ERRORLEVEL%` environment variable:

```
returnvalue = MsgBox("Do. you want to retry?",4,"My Game")
if returnvalue = 7 then
    WScript.Quit 2
else
    WScript.Quit 1
end if
```

Then use the following in your batch file:

```
START /WAIT "" "C:\Velocity DK\My Game\Invalid.vbs"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 GOTO RETRY
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 2 GOTO FORCE_QUIT
```

### Further Reading

- [Choice - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html)
- [Errorlevel - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html)